# What does the MATLAB *. operator do?

Tags: matlab

I see this in a MATLAB m-script, don't know what the `*.` operator is:

```
6*.5 = 3
10*.1 = 1
10*.30 = 3
```

So, what is the `*.` operator doing?

Comment: The trick is to add spaces. `6 *. 5` shows a syntax error in the MATLAB Editor, and also when you try to run it. `6 * .5` works fine. So the `.` belongs to the number that comes after, not to the `*` operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, the `.` means element by element operation.

In this case (from syntax highlighting) it looks like a regular decimal point though!

Comment: Oh my! I think you are right, it is just a simple multiplication! I suppose we can delete this question, I've been searching everywhere.

Comment: Syntax highlight should confirm for you that the . is part of the .5 or .1 or whatever.

Comment: Well, I am running it in MATLAB R2021b version and there is no syntax highlighting that gives any hint whatsoever.

Comment: Hint: in elementwise operations (and transposition) the `.` comes first.